# Counting the number of occurences for each row in oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have a table with two columns name and disease , and i want to count the number of time each disease is found in the table for example

```
------------------------
name       | disease   |
------------------------
name1      | a         |
------------------------
name2      | b         |
------------------------
name3      | c         |
------------------------
name4      | a , b , d |
------------------------
```

i'm looking for a query that would give me a result like this , is it possible? I tried a lot of queries and none of them worked the way i wanted to

```
------------------------
a          |  2        |
------------------------
b          |  2        |
------------------------
c          |  1        |
------------------------
d          |  1        |
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read comments within code:

```
SQL> with test as
  2    -- sample data
  3   (select 'name1' as name, 'a' as disease from dual union all
  4    select 'name2' as name, 'b' as disease from dual union all
  5    select 'name3' as name, 'c' as disease from dual union all
  6    select 'name4' as name, 'a , b , d' as disease from dual
  7   ),
  8  splt as
  9   -- split the DISEASE column to rows
 10   (select name,
 11      trim(regexp_substr(disease, '[^,]+', 1, column_value)) disease
 12    from test cross
 13    join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 14                             connect by level <= regexp_count(disease, ',') + 1
 15                            ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 16   )
 17  -- finally ...
 18  select disease,
 19         count(*) num
 20  from splt
 21  group by disease
 22  order by disease;

DISEASE           NUM
---------- ----------
a                   2
b                   2
c                   1
d                   1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TEST_TABE AS (
SELECT 'name1' as name, 'a' AS disease FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'name2' as name, 'b' AS disease FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'name3' as name, 'c' AS disease FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'name4' as name, 'a , b , d' AS disease FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN INSTR(disease, 'a') != 0 THEN 1 END) AS "A",
    SUM(CASE WHEN INSTR(disease, 'b') != 0 THEN 1 END) AS "B",
    SUM(CASE WHEN INSTR(disease, 'c') != 0 THEN 1 END) AS "C",
    SUM(CASE WHEN INSTR(disease, 'd') != 0 THEN 1 END) AS "D"
FROM TEST_TABE;
```

Results:

```
A   B   C   D
2   2   1   1
```

Comment: Well ... yes, but it doesn't scale. What if disease `f` appears in the table? You'll have to modify the whole query for **each** new disease.

Comment: If that's a requirement, OP can update the question and downvote this answer. I assumed this was part of some class assignment given that the table isn't even in first normal form. The disease column isn't atomic. If this is for a production DB, good luck OP.